# Asp menu control formatting sitemapnode

Tags: css, formatting, styling, sitemapnode

I'm trying to figured out how to separately format sitemapnodes which do not have a URL associated. Here's a code example:

```
<siteMapNode title="TheThingIWantFormattedSeparately">
  <siteMapNode url="~/pages/customer.aspx" title="Customer"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/pages/contract.aspx" title="Contract"/>
```

So I'm wanting the FIRST sitemapnode to look different than the other sitemapnodes. Is this possible? I'm digging around but am not finding much out there.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but this might help: [CSS friendly menus with ASP.NET Menu control, jQuery and Superfish](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Fun/Superfish/).